# Generating random 0/1 matrix with fixed features in R

Tags: r, matrix, random

I want to generate a random `M x N` matrix with zeros and ones with the following special properties:

1) The ones are only in `m` of the `M` rows.

2) The ones are only in `n` of the `N` columns.

Suppose I am ONLY given that `M=10`, `N=10`, `m=6` and `n=4`. One possible random matrix is given by

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    1     0
 [2,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    1     0
 [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [5,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0     0
 [6,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [8,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [9,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1     0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
```

For reproducibility, I've artificially generated the above "random" matrix using

```
ex <- matrix(0,10,10)
ex[1,3] <- ex[1,7] <- ex[1,9] <- ex[2,3] <- ex[2,7] <- 
  ex[2,9] <- ex[5,3] <- ex[5,7] <- ex[6,2] <- ex[8,3] <- ex[9,3] <- ex[9,9] <- 1
```

Note that

```
sum(rowSums(ex)>0)
[1] 6
sum(colSums(ex)>0)
[1] 4
```

which match exactly `m` and `n` above. The number of ones can be random. On one extreme I could have 6 ones spread out over 6 rows and 4 columns (2 columns will have 2 ones, while the rest have 1) or on the other extreme, I could have 24 ones (each of the 6 rows will have a 1 in the same 4 columns).

**Question**
I can generate this in a brute force manner, sampling over the rows and columns, but I need to do this over thousands of such matrices (because the `m` and `n` will be different each time) and these matrices are large (`M=5000` and `N=8000`, typically). Is there a way to do this efficiently in `R`?

Comment: Is it stupid to ask what probability distribution do you want using this method. In fact you are conditionning with `m` and `n`.

Comment: I don't have a particular distribution in mind - uniformly over the indices is good enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
M=10 #total number rows
N=10 #total number columns
m=6 #number valid rows
n=4 #number valid columns

#number of cells to simulate
k=12

ex <- matrix(0,M,N)

#sample m valid rows and n valid columns from uniform
mi <- sample(1:M, m) 
ni <- sample(1:N, n)

#get all valid cells (valid rows and columns)
mn_i <- expand.grid(mi, ni)

#sample k cells from valid cells
x <- mn_i[sample(1:nrow(mn_i), k), ]

#update sampled cells using matrix subet on ex
ex[as.matrix(x)] <- 1

# > ex
# [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0     1
# [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [5,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0     1
# [6,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0     0
# [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     1
# [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
```

You might want to wrap in a function to call it something like

```
 ex <- constrained_matrix_sample(M, N, m, n, k)
```

Comment: Is there a way to constrain it even further to have exactly `m=6` rows that have non-zero sum? In your example there are only 5 such rows. Changing the seed will certainly change it, but I will have to do this over thousands of matrices (different combos of `M`,`N`,`m`,`n`), and a single seed might not guarantee that property I need.

Comment: do you want to equally distribute the randomly selected cells among rows and columns or simply ensure that each candidate row and column has at least one? E.g., in the example above, k = 12 cells are selected from 24 (m x n) possible cells, where each cell has equal chance of selection. by chance, none of those selected came from one of the candidate rows.

Comment: I'd like to ensure that each candidate row and column has at least one hit (i.e. 1).

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr` variant

```
M = 10 # rows
N = 10 # columns
m = 6
n = 4

ni = sample(1:N, n)
mi = sample(1:M, m)

expand.grid(N = 1:N, M = 1:M) %>% 
  mutate(value = ifelse(N %in% ni & M %in% mi, 1, 0)) %>% 
  .$value %>% 
  matrix(., nrow = M, byrow = TRUE)
```